# Increase process priority with pthread_win32

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, pthreads

Environment: Win XP, Visual C++

I'm using the pthread_win32 library in order to implement threads in my program, and I want to raise my process (program) priority to HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS.  Is there any function in the library that allows this kind of operation?

Otherwise, is it possible to use the `SetPriorityClass` function with `pthread_win32, or must I use the win threads to ensure some compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a native thread handle on which to call [`SetPriorityClass`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [`pthread_getw32threadhandle_np`](http://sourceware.org/pthreads-win32/manual/pthread_getw32threadhandle_np.html).